# Can de VS2010 SQL Server 2008 Project type be used to do migrations

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, deployment, migration

I just started using the new project type SQL Server 2008 Database. I can manage the complete schema in detail, but I don't see how I can use the deployment to do versioning like I can with migrations in Ruby on Rails.

There is always just one version of a table (CREATE TABLE), and I see no way to go forward and backwards in time with the schema. Although technically forward would just be a matter of deploying after changes, there's no way to go backwards, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a version control system, like TFS, SourceSafe, SVN etc.

Comment: I have a version control system (SVN) but how would one go about a rollback of the database (with data)?

Comment: Backing up the database.  You can't use a database project to track structure and data.